# zoom buttons in android's web browser

Tags: android, web

The web-site I'm working on is specially designed for Android. The user will not get benefit from Android build-in zoom buttons. On the contrary they make a mess.
How can I switch them off?

Comment: Interesting question. The google online apps are able to do that, e.g. the mobile Google Reader doesn't show the zoom controls.

Comment: are you referring to the build-in application using the webkit-browser-control or the Google Reader site while browsing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the following code casts magic

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```